# create-rmi-keystore.bat askme again and again

Tags: jmeter

when i start create-rmi-keystore.bat ,it ask me again and again
it make me cry
note
链接：http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=98be310f68a89b958da9ff5d87b44ca0&sub=AF9319467D6842BFA357F0D5A5F09818
CMD:
    您的名字与姓氏是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    您的组织单位名称是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    您的组织名称是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    您所在的城市或区域名称是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    您所在的省/市/自治区名称是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    该单位的双字母国家/地区代码是什么?
      [Unknown]:  x
    CN=x, OU=x, O=x, L=x, ST=x, C=x是否正确?
      [否]:  yes
    您的名字与姓氏是什么?
      [x]:  x
    您的组织单位名称是什么?
      [x]:  x
    您的组织名称是什么?
      [x]:  xx
    您所在的城市或区域名称是什么?
      [x]:  x
    您所在的省/市/自治区名称是什么?
      [x]:  x
    该单位的双字母国家/地区代码是什么?
      [x]:  x
    CN=x, OU=x, O=xx, L=x, ST=x, C=x是否正确?
      [否]:  xx
    您的名字与姓氏是什么?
      [x]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This secure RMI communication between JMeter master and slaves in distributed testing is something which doesn't make a lot of sense to me therefore I used to turn it off as encrypting and decrypting the data which is not sensitive just consumes resources and doesn't add any value.

So if you don't explicitly require this you can turn the feature off by adding the next line to *user.properties* file on master and all the slaves:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

Once done JMeter will not be looking for the `rmi_keystore.jks` any more.

References:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Alternatively you could just copy the aforementioned `rmi_keystore.jks` file from Linux machine to Windows, you don't need to regenerate it everywhere, it must be present and match on master and slaves

Answer (score 0):

Did you type « yes » for last answer ?

From what I translate, keytool asked « is it correct » and it seems it expected yes/no and didn’t get yes,  that’s why it asks again.

It’s not jmeter specific, it’s jdk keytool

Comment: yes,I am sure I had typed 'yes'.before this situation,I create a key in linux successfully.But I fail in win10 with create-rmi-keystore.bat.